# How to find the string of yacc rule?

Tags: compiler-construction, yacc, lex

Say I have a yacc rule like: Token: ID '(' VALUES ')'.

How can I get the lexeme of this rule, I.E. "foo(bar, baz)".

The rules for each of these productions, I.E. VALUES or ID, are all currently working, I just don't know how to print the current lexeme.

Comment: I don't know what you believe "lexeme" means; your usage is confusing. `)` is a lexeme. The production right-hand side you list matches five lexemes, apparently. (Or maybe four, if `VALUES` is really a token, but that would be a very strange token.) There's no such thing as a "current lexeme" in the parser. Parser symbols (both non-terminals and terminals) have semantic values, which are set in the semantic action associated with the production.

Comment: @rici you're right, I was not using lexeme correctly. I mean the string of the token, not the lexeme. Essentially, I want to be able to print "foo(bar, baz)" to stdout in the semantic action, in the above example.

Comment: Why? I ask because if you want that for debugging purposes, there's probably a simpler solution. By and large, the point of parsing is to break an input text into meaningful pieces and show their relationship. Just putting them back together into the original string doesn't really do much in that regard.

Comment: @rici I'm trying to construct a symbol table, which i plan on hashing the lexeme (for example the variable name "foo" would be stored in the symbol table at it's hash value). I was planning on using the above printf example to debug.

Comment: Personally, I would have put `foo` in the symbol table before it got to your `Token` production. I might even have done it in the lexical scanner, depending on parser design, although some people feel that the scanner should be more isolated from semantics. But that doesn't have anything to do with debugging :-) To start with, the easiest way of debugging a parser is to use Bison's trace facility, which is described in the "Debugging your parser" section in the [Bison manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/bison.html#Tracing).

Comment: TL;DR version: Add `-t` to your bison command. Insert `yydebug = 1;` in your `main()` function. (Or `yydebug = 0` if you don't want to see traces; I generally use a command-line option to turn debugging off and on.)

Comment: @rici So, I got the symbol table working for basic ID's using the lexer option you mentioned. However, I'm struggling with discerning functions from arrays from ints, because the lexer grabs the lexeme for variable name. Something that seems easier, to me, is if I could take the production ID '(' VALUES ')' and break it down into each individual lexeme. I had thought something like using $1, $2 etc. in the semantic action would accomplish this, but those special values all seem to be ints. Also, -t is super helpful for debugging, thank you.

Comment: By default, semantic values are integers. You're expected to customise according to your needs, though. A good start would be to read the [Bison manual section on semantic types](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/bison.html#Semantics). In the particular case of symbols, I'd make the semantic type of a symbol (i.e. `ID`) be a reference to the symbol table entry. In that case, `$1` in your function call production will be precisely that symbol table entry, and the associated action can update the entry to register the fact that the symbol is used as a function.